# Automatic made "main" class in new JFrame at netbeans GUI design

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, program-entry-point

When I create a new JFrame in Netbeans there is a main class which has been automatically created. Even if I put it inside `/* */` the code works fine. I learnt in any java program there must only one main class which is starting point of the program.

1. What is the usage of the main class in the JFrame?
2. Is there any problem if I keep it or delete it?
3. When can I call the code inside the main class?

---

```
//    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
       /* try {
                          System.out.println("111111111111111");
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
/*
        /* Create and display the form 
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //welcomeUser.setText("Welcome");
                System.out.println("111111111111111");
                //new Welcome().setVisible(true);     
                System.out.println("333333333333333");
            }
        });*/
  //  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the usage of the main class in the JFrame?

As you have already stated, every program must have a entry point, which is automatically called by the JVM.  The fun fact is, you can have multiple class each with a `main` method.  From the IDE, you can identify the "main" class that should be used to launch the program or run another class that has a `main` method manually (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> or right click|Run)

A Jar file may contain a manifest entry that points to the preferred "main" class to execute when the jar is run as well.

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) for more details on `main` and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more details on setting an application's entry point with a Jar

> Is there any problem if I keep it or delete it?

No.  But, if you application does not have another class with a `main` method in it, it will no longer run.

> When can I call the code inside the main class?

Technically, you don't.  It is called on you behalf.  If you don't want your `JFrame` class to have a `main` method (and there's nothing wrong with this), you can instantiate the frame from another class (perhaps even from within that classes' `main` method if that what's called for)

Comment: Before JUnit was written, it was common to put test code into a main method of the class you wanted to test. Fortunately, that is obsolete.